# Oracle Java stored procedures classpath order

Tags: java, database, oracle, stored-procedures, loadjava

In a standard JVM I can re-order my classpath to "hide" similar classes (move desired implementation of a class/interface to the front of the classpath). How I can achieve this behaviour in the internal database JVM (e.g. 11g)? Is this the order of loading the classes with "loadjava"?

Comment: @Florin Ghita: It belongs to Oracle RDMBS, the "loadjava" tool is necessary to load java code into an Oracle DB. So I think, the tag "Oracle" was correct.

Comment: sorry, I've rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `loadJava` utility to load a class there is only a single path on the class-path.

If you load a class that has the same name and class path as a previous class then it will ignore the newer class unless you specify the [`-force` option](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/cheleven.htm#CACFHDJE):

> `-force`  Forces files to be loaded, even if they match digest table entries.

In which case it will overwrite the earlier entry (it will not load two copies of the class).

So, no, you cannot hide duplicate classes by re-ordering the class-path (as you can with external JVMs) as there is only a single path on the class-path within the internal JVM used by Oracle.

Comment: Ah, thank you. So I have to order the loadjava calls and have to execute it in the reverse order than it occurs on the classpath.

Comment: No, you can do it in the order of the class path and not specify the `-force` option. In which case, all later duplicates should be ignored.